# Capturar valor de de H1 e setar em outro H1 com jquery, com click

Tags: jquery

tenho a seguinte situação, tenho dois h1 em locais distintos no web site, gostaria que ao clicar o valor de um h1, passasse para o outro.

Comment: Existe alguma relação entre eles na àrvore do DOM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imaginando que os dois H1 estejam na mesma pagina, segue abaixo com vc deveria fazer usando o Jquery:

```js
function Capture(){
  var _text = $('#primeiro_h1').html();
  $('#segundo_h1').html(_text);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="primeiro_h1">Seu primeiro H1</h1>
<h1 id="segundo_h1">Seu segundo H1</h1>
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="Capture();">Click para capiturar</a>
```

Agora se a ideia é fazer com que o valor mude conforme seja clicado em algum elemento seria assim:

```js
$('#bto_click').click(function(){
  var _text = $('#primeiro_h1').html();
  $('#segundo_h1').html(_text);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="primeiro_h1">Seu primeiro H1</h1>
    <h1 id="segundo_h1">Seu segundo H1</h1>
    <a href="javascript:;" id="bto_click">Click para capiturar</a>
```

Qualquer duvida é só gritar!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Segue o script para mudança de valores entre dois h1:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('h1').click(function() {

    var prevH1 = $(this).prev('h1').html();
    var nextH1 = $(this).next('h1').html();
    var thisH1 = $(this).html();

    if (nextH1) {
      $(this).html(nextH1);
      $(this).next('h1').html(thisH1);
    } else {
      $(this).html(prevH1);
      $(this).prev('h1').html(thisH1);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>

<h1>Título</h1>
```